# Only the zygote can create the global boot image

Tags: android, dalvik

I am trying to modify Android framework *.dex file. I rebuilt `boot.oat` and `boot.oat` in /system/framework/arm64, it is fine. Then I remove all odex file in `/data/dalvik-cache/`. When I reboot, it is supposed the new `boot.oat` will generate `*.odex` in cache. But Android cannot boot, shows cannot relocate `boot.oat` to `/dalvik-cache`, Only the zygote can create the global boot image.

How to resolve?

Comment: This might be more appropriate to ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/.